# How to solve this ODE $(x^3+y^3)\,dx=3x^2y\,dy$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a good way to solve this ODE $$(x^3+y^3)\,dx=3x^2y\,dy$$

I work it until $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac13\left(\frac xy+ \left(\frac yx\right)^2\right)$$

and let $u=\frac{y}{x}$

I cannot go on.... It seems difficult to integrate.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1):

$u =\dfrac{y}{x} \implies y = ux \implies y' = u + xu' \implies 3u + 3xu' = \dfrac{1}{u} + u^2\implies 3x\dfrac{du}{dx} = u^2+\dfrac{1}{u}-3u= \dfrac{u^3-3u^2+1}{u}\implies \displaystyle \int \dfrac{udu}{u^3-3u^2+1}= \displaystyle \int \dfrac{dx}{3x} \implies \displaystyle \sum_{\{c: c^3-3c^2+1 = 0\}} \dfrac{\log (u-c)}{c-2}= \ln |x|+K, K:$ constant according to Wolfram Alpha.

**Note:** If this is a math model to solve an applications, the best method would be the Euler's method.